# base64 decode/encode inconsistency

Tags: php, encoding, base64, decoding

I'm attempting to reverse engineer an application of base64 encoding which is utilised by a third party project, so I can create a custom UI. My method has been successful with one example but appears to not quite be hitting the mark in other examples (a few characters which aren't quite right).

```
AQAAAAAAGQBec2lwOigwMjAxMjM0NTZbMC05XSspQC4qFwBzaXA6MDIwMTIyMTEzQDEyNy4wLjAuMQAA
```

^^ actual base64 encoding within database

```
AQAAAAAAEABec2lwOigwMjAxMjM0NTZbMC05XSspQC4qEwBzaXA6MDIwMTIyMTEzQDEyNy4wLjAuMQoA
```

^^ best attempt to match with PHP method

Due to control characters I've implemented some json encoding to make it easier to identify the strings which are being used for variables. The strings match for this example but the base64 encoding result is different to the actual which is expected.

```
$actualfour = 'AQAAAAAAGQBec2lwOigwMjAxMjM0NTZbMC05XSspQC4qFwBzaXA6MDIwMTIyMTEzQDEyNy4wLjAuMQAA';
echo "".$actualfour;
echo "<br />";

    $four = chr(01);
    $four .= chr(00);
    $four .= chr(00);
    $four .= chr(00);
    $four .= chr(00);
    $four .= chr(00);
    $four .= chr(16);
    $four .= chr(00);
    $four .= '^sip:(020123456[0-9]+)@.*';
    $four .= chr(19);
    $four .= chr(00);
    $four .= 'sip:020122113@127.0.0.1
'.chr(00);

$jsonfour = json_encode($four);
echo "unencoded: ".$jsonfour;
echo "<br />";
$encodefour = base64_encode($four);
echo "".$encodefour;
echo "<br />";
$jsonencodefour = json_encode(base64_decode($encodefour));
echo "encoded: ".$jsonencodefour;
echo "<br />";

if ($encodefour != $actualfour) { echo "FAIL"; } else { echo "PASS"; }
```

^^ Code Method

```
AQAAAAAAGQBec2lwOigwMjAxMjM0NTZbMC05XSspQC4qFwBzaXA6MDIwMTIyMTEzQDEyNy4wLjAuMQAA
unencoded: "\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0010\u0000^sip:(020123456[0-9]+)@.*\u0013\u0000sip:020122113@127.0.0.1\n\u0000"
AQAAAAAAEABec2lwOigwMjAxMjM0NTZbMC05XSspQC4qEwBzaXA6MDIwMTIyMTEzQDEyNy4wLjAuMQoA
encoded:   "\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0010\u0000^sip:(020123456[0-9]+)@.*\u0013\u0000sip:020122113@127.0.0.1\n\u0000"
FAIL
```

^^ Output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors in `$four`.

- `chr(16)` should be `chr(0x19)` or `chr(25)`
- `chr(13)` should be `chr(0x17)` or `chr(23)`
- The newline after `127.0.0.1` should be `chr(00)`

Here's the correct `$four`:

```
$four = chr(01);
$four .= chr(00);
$four .= chr(00);
$four .= chr(00);
$four .= chr(00);
$four .= chr(00);
$four .= chr(0x19);
$four .= chr(00);
$four .= '^sip:(020123456[0-9]+)@.*';
$four .= chr(0x17);
$four .= chr(00);
$four .= 'sip:020122113@127.0.0.1'.chr(00).chr(00);
```

You can find all these discrepancies by comparing `json_encode(base64_decode($actualfour))` with `json_encode($four)`. Remember that when it shows a control character as `\u####` that the number is hex, not decimal.